# Follow-up no intent is not working and throwing MalformedResponse

Tags: node.js, dialogflow-es, google-assistant-sdk

I'm trying to create Action on Google using the DialogFlow. And using a concept of follow-up intent. 
My Intent structure is given below,

```
default-fallback 
default-welcome  
invoice-number
     |- invoice-number-no
     |- invoice-number-yes
            |-part-number
                     |-part-number-yes
                     |-part-number-no
```

I think there is no issue with my code(fulfillment) because,

1. I'm able to reach till "part-number" now I have two option yes and no.

   > (invoice-number->invoice-number-yes->part-number)

   If say yes, it is working perfectly but when I say no, it is not even 
   calling webhook, and directly throwing MalformedResponse error.

   #### Error:

   > MalformedResponse Failed to parse DialogFlow response into AppResponse
   >   because of empty speech response.
2. I compared intents available in DialogFlow and intent implemented in my webhook, and it seems I implemented all intents. Still, let say I forgot to implement intent then I think, action on google lib will throw no matching intent expectation if it trys to find intent which is not implemented. But there is no such error either.

What can be a solution for this?

Thanks in advance

Comment: If you have a: `"MalformedResponse"` error, then the issue is most likely with the code. So please show the code :)

Comment: @MarcosCasagrande, I gave two reasons that it cannot be a code issue. Can you please suggest how can I verify that it is a code issue?